# Slider slides not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on developing a slider component with a slide effect. My goal is to have multiple slides transition seamlessly. However, I'm encountering an issue where only the first slide in the sequence is displaying properly. The subsequent slides, which are supposed to follow the first one, are not appearing at all. This is puzzling because the functionality seems to work perfectly for the initial slide, but fails to continue for the rest of the slides.

```js
let currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(currentSlideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(currentSlideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    currentSlideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    currentSlideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  // Aggiornamento per l'animazione
  let slideWidth = slides[0].clientWidth;
  let moveX = -((currentSlideIndex - 1) * slideWidth);
  document.querySelector('.slides').style.transform = `translateX(${moveX}px)`;

  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  dots[currentSlideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.slide {
  flex: none;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-container no-on-desktop">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div class="column">
          <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
            <img src="http://resinpro.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Untitled-2.png" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="img-title bold">Gussteile für große Tische</p>
            <p style="color: #565656;" class="img-description">Epoxytable FIVE 5 ist die perfekte Lösung für spektakuläre Tische. Seine einzigartige Formulierung hält künstlerischen Herausforderungen stand und ermöglicht Gussstücke mit einer Dicke von bis zu 2 Zoll. Mit niedriger Exothermie und Kratzfestigkeit
              ist es ideal für die Herstellung von langlebigen Holz- und Harztischen unter allen Umweltbedingungen.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <div class="column">
          <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
            <img src="http://resinpro.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Untitled-3.png" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="img-title bold">Für Couchtische</p>
            <p style="color: #565656;" class="img-description">Dank Epoxytable FIVE 5 werden Ihre Couchtische zu wahren Schmuckstücken. Mit diesem Harz haben Sie unendlich viele Gestaltungsmöglichkeiten, um Ihre Individualität auszudrücken und Stücke zu schaffen, die Ihren einzigartigen Geschmack und
              Stil widerspiegeln. Das Ergebnis? Ein Zuhause, das durch Eleganz und Persönlichkeit bereichert wird.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide3">
        <div class="column">
          <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
            <img src="http://resinpro.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Untitled-4.png" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="img-title bold">Für markante Tische</p>
            <p style="color: #565656;" class="img-description">Dank Epoxytable FIVE 5 sind Ihre Tische mit Meereswelleneffekt eine unglaubliche Überraschung für jeden, der Ihr Haus betritt. Dieses Harz gibt Ihnen die Möglichkeit, Stücke zu kreieren, die die Fantasie anregen und die Erfahrung Ihrer Gäste
              unvergesslich machen.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Aggiungi altre slide se necessario -->
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving `.slides` within `.slider` therefore the `overflow:hidden` should be on the `.slider`.

Move the overflow from .slides to .slider:

```js
let currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(currentSlideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(currentSlideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    currentSlideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    currentSlideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  // Aggiornamento per l'animazione
  let slideWidth = slides[0].clientWidth;
  let moveX = -((currentSlideIndex - 1) * slideWidth);
  document.querySelector('.slides').style.transform = `translateX(${moveX}px)`;

  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  dots[currentSlideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.slide {
  flex: none;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slides {
  display: flex;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-container no-on-desktop">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div class="column">
          <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
            <img src="http://resinpro.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Untitled-2.png" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="img-title bold">Gussteile für große Tische</p>
            <p style="color: #565656;" class="img-description">Epoxytable FIVE 5 ist die perfekte Lösung für spektakuläre Tische. Seine einzigartige Formulierung hält künstlerischen Herausforderungen stand und ermöglicht Gussstücke mit einer Dicke von bis zu 2 Zoll. Mit niedriger Exothermie und Kratzfestigkeit
              ist es ideal für die Herstellung von langlebigen Holz- und Harztischen unter allen Umweltbedingungen.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <div class="column">
          <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
            <img src="http://resinpro.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Untitled-3.png" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="img-title bold">Für Couchtische</p>
            <p style="color: #565656;" class="img-description">Dank Epoxytable FIVE 5 werden Ihre Couchtische zu wahren Schmuckstücken. Mit diesem Harz haben Sie unendlich viele Gestaltungsmöglichkeiten, um Ihre Individualität auszudrücken und Stücke zu schaffen, die Ihren einzigartigen Geschmack und
              Stil widerspiegeln. Das Ergebnis? Ein Zuhause, das durch Eleganz und Persönlichkeit bereichert wird.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide3">
        <div class="column">
          <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
            <img src="http://resinpro.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Untitled-4.png" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="img-title bold">Für markante Tische</p>
            <p style="color: #565656;" class="img-description">Dank Epoxytable FIVE 5 sind Ihre Tische mit Meereswelleneffekt eine unglaubliche Überraschung für jeden, der Ihr Haus betritt. Dieses Harz gibt Ihnen die Möglichkeit, Stücke zu kreieren, die die Fantasie anregen und die Erfahrung Ihrer Gäste
              unvergesslich machen.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Aggiungi altre slide se necessario -->
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```